# Python applications crash with module errors

Tags: python

I just updated some software on my system, and now I get a bizarre error every time I try to start a program that uses Python, even though all of the dependencies on my system have been resolved properly. Exaile outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/exaile/exaile.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/exaile/exaile.py", line 80, in main
    from xl import main
  File "/usr/lib/exaile/xl/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    from xl.nls import gettext as _
  File "/usr/lib/exaile/xl/nls.py", line 33, in <module>
    import locale
ImportError: No module named locale
```

And running `sudo add-apt-repository` outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 34, in <module>
    import threading
ImportError: No module named 'threading'
```

I have no idea why this would happen because I have all dependencies resolved on my system, which means I shouldn't be missing anything. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I need this issue fixed soon. My system has broken packages and I can't fix it until I fix this issue so that the installation scripts will work.

Comment: I found a solution! I had to start a live CD and run a command to copy all files /usr/lib/py* to my installation. When I rebooted into my system, Python partially worked, but still had a few problems. This was solved by reinstalling all of my Python packages with the command sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep ^python)

Comment: Must have been that the modules were never there in the first place. Hm, that's odd.

Comment: Whats the output of `python --version` ?

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste you should probably post your solution as an answer to your question and select it, that will help other people in the future having the same problem as you.

Comment: @DorianDore Normally, that wouldn't be a bad idea. However, I don't think I will for a couple of reasons. As you've already said, the modules were never there in the first place, which meant that I'd probably deleted them myself, which is pretty likely with how much I play with my system's inner workings. This issue is probably specific to me and what I did seems more like a dirty workaround than a solution anyway. Meh, it doesn't matter anyway. This question hasn't had any activity since April. I think we're done here. I will accept your answer though, because it's a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may need to set your Python environment path. First, go in your terminal, and execute the command, `echo $PYTHONPATH`. This variable may be empty. If so, you can create a new one. Do this by executing the command `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.x/` If this works, append this command to your `~/.bashrc` file. If you cannot locate this file in your home directory, press ctrl+h. Hope I helped!

To test to see if your path was properly set, open a Python shell and do `import test`. If it says, `No module named test` then you didn't properly set your environment variable.